# How to enable a click event in GWT Java?

Tags: java, html, gwt

How do I implement a click event in [Java(GWT)](http://www.gwtproject.org) for this image with an overlaid set of `map` `area` tags?

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow the tutorial on click events? http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/manageevents.html#listening Please make an attempt and ask a specific question about any problems you are having and you are much more likely to get useful help.

Comment: It depends what are you trying to do after click. If you just need to know what was clicked you should read about events as @jwpfox suggests. If you need some kind of navigation after click I would suggest to use [GWT History Mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html).

Comment: Do you want to catch the click anywhere it's clicked, or specifically on the shapes?